# Recursive relationship SQL error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, reference, recursive-query

I am pretty new to SQL and I have a problem. I want to make a recursive relationship (a table that relates to itself), but I get an error when I try to execute my code. It's working fine without the `Coordinator_Office_ID` foreign key.

**The error is:**

> The number of columns in the foreign-key referencing list is not equal
>   to the number of columns in the referenced list.

```
Create table Logistican (
  Office_ID Number(10) Constraint nb_office Not NULL,
  Worker_ID Number(15) Constraint lg_worker not null,
  Name_logistican Varchar(20),
  Room Varchar(10) constraint log_room UNIQUE,
  Coordinator_Office_ID Integer,
  Primary key (Office_ID, Worker_ID),
  Constraint work_id Foreign key (Worker_ID) References worker(worker_ID) on       delete cascade,
  Constraint lg_cord_id Foreign key (Coordinator_Office_ID) References      Logistican(Office_ID)
);
```

Comment: Why do you use different types for `Coordinator_Office_ID` and `Office_ID`?

Comment: I saw that our professor wrote it that way, but i'm not sure if it's correct

Answer (score 2):

Add the constraint with `alter table`:

```
Create table Logistican (
    Office_ID Number(10) Constraint nb_office Not NULL,
    Worker_ID Number(15) Constraint lg_worker not null,
    Name_logistican Varchar(20),
    Room Varchar(10) constraint log_room UNIQUE,
    Coordinator_Office_ID Integer,
    Primary key (Office_ID, Worker_ID),
    Constraint work_id Foreign key (Worker_ID) References worker(worker_ID) on delete cascade
);

alter table Logistican
    add Constraint lg_cord_id
        Foreign key (Coordinator_Office_ID, Worker_Id) References      Logistican(Office_ID, Worker_Id);
```

The relationship needs *all* elements of the primary key to be valid.  I'm not sure if it needs to be a separate statement in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's cause you have defined composite primary key like `Primary key (Office_ID, Worker_ID)` and thus your FK should include both of them else it will result in PFD (partial functional dependency)